# How to make the console wait but then continue without pressing a Key?

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to this community however I'm studying at college on an IT course. And we have been set an assignment to come up with our very own console code. I thought it would be cool and somewhat unique if I program a funny hacker like typerwiter. I have managed to get it to type by itself and be automated so the user doesn't have to do anything for the program to work.

This project is completely experimental and more of a challenge to expand my knowledge and skill however I would like to find out and know how to:

1; Make the program wait.

So for example where my text reads "Initiating decryption..." I would like it to wait, let's say 3 seconds and then carry on. To make it seem as if it's actually processing some sort of data.

2; Make it work on commands.

So I have basic knowledge on switches and if commands. However, I'd like to learn more in-depth on how it all works.
So say in my last text "Would you like to proceed?" I wanted a choice to either close down the console or to carry on with the imaginary decryption. How could I achieve this by then being able to carry on making more text and options for the user to participate?

```
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            var myString = "Initiating decryption..." + Environment.NewLine + "> 248,604 possible combinations found" + Environment.NewLine + "<-> Would you like to proceed?";


            foreach (var character in myString)
            {
                Console.Write(character);
                Thread.Sleep(60);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure why your first question is a problem - making the program wait for 3 seconds - when you are already making the program wait 60ms in your foreach loop.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Answer (score 3):

you can use a Simple if statement and and while bucle to execute the same all time.

```
while(true) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // to waiting 3 seconds
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to proceed ? (Y/N)");
    var option = Console.ReadKey();

    if (option.ToString().ToUpper() == "N"){
           Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget mark as correct If this solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well you want to ask a question to the user, then do something depending on his input.

A basic orientation would be :

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to proceed ? (Y/N)");
string choice = Console.ReadLine();

if (choice == "y")
{`enter code here`
    do something
}
else
{
   do something else
}
```

Comment: You can also make it more solid by putting the second line in a while so you only exit when the user types "y" or "n"...
To go further you can add support for lower and upper cases using `char.ToUpperInvariant(choice) == char.ToUpperInvariant(y)`

Comment: In your code there are two errors - firstly you cannot assign the result of Console.ReadLine to a Char. Secondly you cannot compare a Char & a string. It is always worth testing a solution before posting it to avoid being downvoted.